# Execution flow of recursion program

Tags: c++, recursion

Below is the function that generates permutation.

I need to know the code execution flow of recursion program, I am confused after `search()` lines, I don't understand the two lines after `search()` execution, it should execute at the last or every time. Can someone explain the excution flow of the program step by step?

```cpp
    vector<int> permutation;
    int n = 3;
    bool chosen[n + 1];
    void search() {
      if (permutation.size() == n) {
        // process permutation(print permutation vector)
      } else {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
          if (chosen[i]) continue;
          chosen[i] = true;
          permutation.push_back(i);
          search();
          chosen[i] = false;
          permutation.pop_back();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Recursion isn't really magic, it's just a plain and simple function call. That the call is to the function itself is not that important for the control-flow, it's just another ordinary function call. As for making it easier to follow, use some common debugging practices, like using pen and paper to write down calls into a tree, or use print statements to print before and after doing the call, or just step through the code in a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

In recursive search function is executed until permutation size equal to 3,at return time the boolean is made false and value is returned for future.
Here is the recursion tree--[recursion tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NehJs.png)